# Swift "for" inside of ( ) what is this..?

Tags: swift

```
func getIndex(for priority: Task.Priority) -> Int
{
    prioritizedTasks.firstIndex { $0.priority == priority }!
}
```

what is "for" inside of ()? It is for loop...? what is $0 ? I tried to find them in apple document but I don't know the operator name for them...

Comment: Please read [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166) in the Language Guide. There it's described in detail.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a simple parameter name. You can change that to anything you like so it appears in the method call. You could also leave it out completely. Then, the method call would be:

```
getIndex(priority: ...)
```

instead of:

```
getIndex(for: ...)
```

---

The `$0` is from the `.firstIndex` method. If you don't define a parameter name, then $0 allows you to access the value anyway.
You could also do:

```
prioritizedTasks.firstIndex { task in
    task.priority == priority
}!
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just syntactic sugar. To use that code "as-is", you'd type the following:

`getIndex(for: .taskPriority)`

If you removed it, it would look like this:

```
func getIndex(priority: Task.Priority) -> Int
{
    prioritizedTasks.firstIndex { $0.priority == priority }!
}
```

And this is what it would look like in use:

`getIndex(priority: .taskPriority)`